# Text overflowing off of screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a `navbar` but my text is flowing off of the screen even though I have `overflow: hidden` on my `ul`

Here is my snippet

```css
.header {
  background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.heading {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.nav-items {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <!-- <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo"> -->
    <ul class="nav-items">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://jordanbaron.github.io">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1 class="heading" id="heading"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the .nav-items css class, and change the headers width and height to 100%.

Comment: @sjdm that works, but the header image isnt filling up the viewport height